# AVCaptureDevice cannot find any device for my macOS app ported with Catalyst

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avcapturedevice, mac-catalyst

I try to run my iPad app in MacOS with catalyst.
I want to reach the built-in microphone with following code but cannot succeeded.

```
let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInMicrophone], mediaType: nil, position: .unspecified)
let microphoneDevice = discoverySession.devices.first
let audioCaptureInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphoneDevice!)
```

Last line of code crashes with "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

By the way, with this code the iPad app can reach the microphone successfully.

The output of following is an empty array.

```
print("devices: \(discoverySession.devices)")
```

I tried many things and cannot succeeded.
Do you guys help me with that?

Notes:

- I already enabled microphone usage when prompted.
- Also I added "Microphone Usage Description" in info.plist file.
- In iOS simulator, same error happens because microphone and camera is not available in simulators. But I didn't understand why this happens when running with "My Mac" scheme.

Comment: It seems it is not possible with Catalyst: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123883

Comment: Hope they add this function soon :(